# How to use the last_insert_id() of mysql in jsp(java server pages)

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jsp

I would like to bring the `last_insert_id()` of `mysql` to `jsp` and it should be preserved in a specific variable so that I can use that value in other table. I tried with the help of queries which are already given in `stackoverflow` but returns a value`0`. I already used the `alias` concept also to bring the values in but still it is not working. Can anyone please help me out with this issue? Thanks in advance.
Here is my code

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sairam", "root", "root");
Statement S=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=S.executeQuery("select last_insert_id(),student_name,date_of_admission from student");
%>
<th>Student Id</th>
<th>Student Name</th>
<th>Date of admission</td>
</tr>
<%
while(rs.next())
{
    %>
    <tr>
    <td><%=rs.getString(1) %></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString(3) %></td>



<%
}
%>
```

---

Here is my new code:

```
<form method="post" name="Coursedetails">
    <center><br><h1>COURSE DETAILS</h1></br></center>    
            <table border="1" align="center" bgcolor="white">
<body>
<%
String cn=request.getParameter("course_name");
String cr=request.getParameter("credits");
String pl=request.getParameter("place");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sairam", "root", "root");
Statement S=con.createStatement();
String sql="insert into course(course_name,credits,place) values('"+cn+"','"+cr+"','"+pl+"')";
S.executeUpdate(sql);
 %>

<%
PreparedStatement pst1=con.prepareStatement("select last_insert_id() from course");
ResultSet rs=pst1.executeQuery();
%>
<tr>
<th>course_id</th>
</tr>
<%
while(rs.next())
{
    %>
    <tr>
    <td><%=rs.getInt(1) %></td>
 <%
}
%>
</table>
        </tr>
          <table border="1" align="center" bgcolor="white">
  <% 
  PreparedStatement pst2=con.prepareStatement("select course_name,credits,place from course");
  ResultSet rs1=pst2.executeQuery();
    %>
    <tr>
 <td>course_name</td>
<td>credits</td>
<td>place</td>
</tr>
<%
while(rs1.next())
{
    %>
    <tr>
    <td><%=rs1.getString(1) %></td>
    <td><%=rs1.getString(2) %></td>
    <td><%=rs1.getString(3) %></td>

    <%
}
%>
</table>


    </form>
    </body>
```

`This code is returning same course_id for all the records in the table`.

Comment: Purpose of your requirement is incomplete. `last_insert_id()` will only work if an `insert` is executed in the same SQL `connection` session. Unless no inserts took place, it returns a `zero`. If you really want to store the last insert id in any other table you better go with `after insert` trigger on the table. Call `last_insert_id()` in the same trigger and use it to insert into other table.

Comment: @Ravinder is absolutely right you need get it in same connection session also if insert takes place you can get it by _stmt.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);_ so that you dont need explicitly select it..

Comment: Thanks for your help sir but when I try this it is returning the `same id(value)` for all the columns of student_id in the table.

Comment: These are my `sql queries` and I wanted to execute them through different pages in `jsp` but I couldn't make it.

Comment: `insert into student(student_name) values('sachin');select last_insert_id();set @a=last_insert_id();
insert into course(credits,course_name) values ('3','capstone');
select last_insert_id(); set @b=last_insert_id();
insert into faculty(faculty_name) values('bernard');
select last_insert_id(); set @c=last_insert_id();
insert into class(faculty_id,course_id,semester,day,time) values(@c,@b,'spring 2015','Friday','5.30pm');
select last_insert_id();set @g=last_insert_id();
insert into grades(student_id,class_id,grade) values (@a,@g,'C');`

Comment: `insert into attendance(student_id,class_id,classes_attended,classes_missed) 
values (@a,@g,'25','5');`

Comment: Please can anyone help I'm trying to accomplish this for the past `two` weeks but I couldn't make it so far.

Comment: @sai: what do you mean by *but when I try this it is returning the same id(value) for all the columns of student_id in the table*. Add code that you tried, to the post. NOT in the comments.

Comment: Ok sir. I have posted my code please do check it.